# Multiple gulpfile.js files for different platforms?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

My projects needs to support multiple platforms, but for convenience and because of shared resources I keep these in 1 project directory , something like this :

```
root
 - config
 - platforms
   - browser
   - app
 - resources
 - vendor
```

I now have 1 `gulpfile.js` in the root, which builds both versions at once.

For speed I would like to have 2 separate gulpfiles.

What's the best way to do this? Should I use separate `gulpfile.js` in each version dir ?
Or could I use different `gulpfile.js` filenames, and call these separately ?

I also looked into using tasks, but I use `Laravel` with `Elixir` in the `gulpfile.js` and don't know how to define different tasks with `Elixir`.